# three js, custom animate model gltf

Tags: three.js

I have gltf model.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3BGC.png)

I don't understand how it is possible to make parts of the model move.

how can i make her move like here(click on link).
https://schteppe.github.io/p2.js/demos/ragdoll.html

If possible, tell me how it is possible to implement.
Thanks.

my code (script.js)

```
import { LinearEncoding } from 'three';
import * as THREE from './build/three.module.js';
import {GLTFLoader} from '/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
  
const canvas = document.querySelector('.webgl');
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
let model, fileAnimations, mixer;

(function() {
    loader.load('/model/scene.gltf', 
        function ( gltf ) {
            model = gltf.scene;
            console.log(model);
            scene.add( model );
        },
        function ( xhr ) {
        },
        function (error){
            console.log('error here');
        }
    );

    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 3);
    light.position.set(2,5,5);
    scene.add(light);

    const size = {
        width: window.innerWidth - 50,
        height: window.innerHeight - 50
    }

    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, size.width/size.height, 0.1, 100);
    camera.position.set(0,1,2);
    scene.add(camera);

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGL1Renderer({
        canvas: canvas
    });

    renderer.setSize(size.width, size.height);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.gammaOuput = true;

    let mousePos={x:0, y:0};

    //рендерим игру
    function loop(){
        // Обновляем путина в каждом кадре
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(loop);

        document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove, false);
    }

    // Обрабатываем наше событие
    function handleMouseMove(event) {
    // Конвертируем полученные значение положения мыши
    // в нормализолованное значение между -1 и 1;
    // вот формула для горизонтальной оси:
    var tx = -1 + (event.clientX / size.width)*2;

    // Для вертикальной оси нам необходимо инвертировать
    // нашу формулу, так как в 2D ось Y идет в
    // противоположном направлении, в отличии от оси Y в 3D
    var ty = 1 - (event.clientY / size.height)*2;
    mousePos = {x:tx, y:ty};
    updatePlane();
    }

    function updatePlane(){  
        var targetX = normalize(mousePos.x, -1, 1, -100, 100);
        var targetY = normalize(mousePos.y, -1, 1, 25, 175);
    
        // // Обновляем позицию путина
        // console.log(putin.position);
        model.position.y = mousePos.y;
        model.position.x = mousePos.x;
        model.position.z = 0.1;
    }
    
    function normalize(v,vmin,vmax,tmin, tmax){
        var nv = Math.max(Math.min(v,vmax), vmin);
        var dv = vmax-vmin;
        var pc = (nv-vmin)/dv;
        var dt = tmax-tmin;
        var tv = tmin + (pc*dt);
        return tv;
    
    }

    loop();
}
})();
```

my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ua">
<head>
    <title>Kick putin</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <canvas class="webgl"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
                "three": "./build/three.module.js",
                "/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader":"./loaders/GLTFLoader.js"
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script type="module" src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to find the name of the bones in your model you want to rotate https://jsfiddle.net/bdmrg4oc/1/

```
        loader.load('/model/scene.gltf', function ( gltf ) {

        const model = gltf.scene;
        
        rightArm = model.getObjectByName( 'nameOFBone' );

        scene.add( model );

    } );

 rightArm.rotation.z = variable;
```

to make a model ragdoll you should first get the hang of this, then you will need to add physics and inverse kinimatics